# Rename directory using find returns odd error

Tags: command-line, bash

I have the following command:

`find demoLibrary* -type d -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/demoLibrary/foo}"' - {} \;`

Which do renames the directories `demoLibrary` and `demoLibraryTests` to `foo` and `fooTests` respectively; but also writes the following output:

```
find: ‘./demoLibrary’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./demoLibraryTests’: No such file or directory
```

What is causing that output? Any suggestions on how can I fix that?

Comment: What happens if you use `find -depth ...` ?

Comment: it looks like you are trying to recursive rename those directories, then you need to use `find -depth -type d -name 'dir*'` or find will just traverse those directories set as starting-point. If you just want to rename directories in the current directory you can manage with just the mv statement.

Comment: Yeah. Looks like the problem was traversing the tree. The suggestion worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, a subshell will execute for every match, which can be quite resource-demanding. A better approach would be to pipe the result to rename.

```
$ find -depth -type d \
 -name 'foo*' -print0 | rename -0 -d 's!^foo!bar!'

Reading filenames from file handle (GLOB(0x5594a9a71a48))
./fooone/footwo/foothree renamed as ./fooone/footwo/barthree
./fooone/footwo renamed as ./fooone/bartwo
./fooone renamed as ./barone
```